# With GRDB, use raw sql BUT consume the results in the convenience form?

Tags: swift, grdb

Here's an example SQL query which you can't build using the convenience builders in GRDB...

```
let q = "job.id, job.name, job.city, 

ifnull(jobcategory.value, 'no category'),
ifnull(jobpriority.value, 'no priority'),

from job  

left join jobcategory on job.category = jobcategory.id
left join jobpriority on job.priority = jobpriority.id

where job.user = 13"
```

(indeed, I made an example you can't build in any of the older, less supported iOS Swift SQL libraries either)

and then something like

```
for ..
 let id = ..
 let name = ..
 let city = ..
 let category = ..
 let priority = ..
```

I have heard that with GRDB, you can actually use the raw SQL (i.e., actually not even use the query builder of GRDB), but, in the result **still use the convenience consumption***, with care for types, etc.

If so, in fact how do you do this in the example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GRDB provides a query builder:

```
let persons = try Person.filter(emailColumn != nil).fetchAll(db) // [Person]
```

And it also understands SQL:

```
let persons = try Person.fetchAll(db, "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE email IS NOT NULL")
```

Both code snippets above turn database rows into Person instances. Such conversion is supported by the `RowConvertible` protocol and the full-featured `Record` class provided by GRDB. The code below uses the protocol:

```
struct Person {
    let email: String
    let name: String
}

extension Person : RowConvertible {
    init(row: Row) {
        email = row.value(named: "email")
        name = row.value(named: "name")
    }
}
```

The `init(row:)` constructor is used for both the "query interface" request `Person.filter(...).fetchAll(db)`, and the SQL request `Person.fetchAll(db, "SELECT ...")`.

That's what is meant by **GRDB does not punish you when you want to use raw SQL**. Your custom record types support both query interface requests and SQL requests out of the box. It is just as easy to fetch records with both techniques:

```
// Two one-liners:
let persons = try Person.filter(emailColumn != nil).fetchAll(db)
let persons = try Person.fetchAll(db, "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE email IS NOT NULL")
```

Now, your example can be written as:

```
struct Job {
    let id: Int64
    let name: String
    let city: String
    let category: String
    let priority: String
}

extension Job : RowConvertible {
    init(row: Row) {
        id = row.value(named: "id")
        name = row.value(named: "name")
        city = row.value(named: "city")
        category = row.value(named: "category")
        priority = row.value(named: "priority")
    }
}

try dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
    let q = "SELECT job.id, job.name, job.city, " +
        " IFNULL(jobcategory.value, 'no category') AS category, " +
        " IFNULL(jobpriority.value, 'no priority') AS priority " +
        "FROM job " +
        "LEFT JOIN jobcategory ON job.category = jobcategory.id " +
        "LEFT JOIN jobpriority ON job.priority = jobpriority.id " +
        "WHERE job.user = 13"

    let jobs = try Job.fetchAll(db, q)
}
```

Since category and priority are not columns of jobs, you may prefer splitting the above struct in two:

```
struct Job {
    let id: Int64
    let name: String
    let city: String
}

struct ExtendedJob {
    let job: Job
    let category: String
    let priority: String
}

extension Job : RowConvertible {
    init(row: Row) {
        id = row.value(named: "id")
        name = row.value(named: "name")
        city = row.value(named: "city")
    }
}

extension ExtendedJob : RowConvertible {
    init(row: Row) {
        job = Job(row: row)
        category = row.value(named: "category")
        priority = row.value(named: "priority")
    }
}

try dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
    let q = "SELECT job.id, job.name, job.city, " +
        " IFNULL(jobcategory.value, 'no category') AS category, " +
        " IFNULL(jobpriority.value, 'no priority') AS priority " +
        "FROM job " +
        "LEFT JOIN jobcategory ON job.category = jobcategory.id " +
        "LEFT JOIN jobpriority ON job.priority = jobpriority.id " +
        "WHERE job.user = 13"

    let jobs = try ExtendedJob.fetchAll(db, q)
}
```

You can finally encapsulate the custom SQL query in a "custom requests":

```
extension ExtendedJob {
    static func filter(userId: Int64) -> AnyTypedRequest<ExtendedJob> {
        let request = SQLRequest(
            "SELECT job.id, job.name, job.city, " +
            " IFNULL(jobcategory.value, 'no category') AS category, " +
            " IFNULL(jobpriority.value, 'no priority') AS priority " +
            "FROM job " +
            "LEFT JOIN jobcategory ON job.category = jobcategory.id " +
            "LEFT JOIN jobpriority ON job.priority = jobpriority.id " +
            "WHERE job.user = ?",
            arguments: [userId])
        return request.asRequest(of: ExtendedJob.self)
    }
}

// No SQL in sight:
let jobs = try dbQueue.inDatabase { db in
    try ExtendedJob.filter(userId: 13).fetchAll(db)
}
```

Comment: Beautifully explained. God bless for saving me loads of head trouble.

Comment: Thanks @user2672052, even if this sample code needs to be updated for the latest version of GRDB: `RowConvertible` has been renamed `FetchableRecord`, and `row.value(named:...)` is now a subscript `row[...]`.